# How to check does array key exist in defined constant array [PHP 7 define()]

Tags: php, arrays, constants, defined, php-7

**PHP7 brought possibility define array constants with define(). In PHP 5.6, they could only be defined with const.**

So I can use [`define( string $name , mixed $value ))`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) to set array of constants, but it seems that it forgot to bring also upgrade of [`defined ( mixed $name )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) along since it still only accepts `string` value or am I missing something?

`PHP v: < 7` I had to define every animal separately `define('ANIMAL_DOG', 'black');`, `define('ANIMAL_CAT', 'white');` etc. or serialize my *zoo*.

`PHP v: >= 7` I can define entire *zoo* which is freaking awesome, but I can't find my animal in the *zoo* as simply I can find single ANIMAL. It is reasonable in the real world, but here's supplementary question if I haven't miss something.

Is that intentional that defined(); does not accept array?. If I define my zoo...

```php
define('ANIMALS', array(
    'dog' => 'black',
    'cat' => 'white',
    'bird' => 'brown'
));
```

... why can't I find my dog simply `defined('ANIMALS' => 'dog');`?

**1.** Prints always: `The dog was not found`

```
print (defined('ANIMALS[dog]')) ? "1. Go for a walk with the dog\n" : "1. The dog was not found\n";
```

**2.** Prints always: `The dog was not found` and when dog really does not exist shows Notice + Warning

```
/** if ANIMALS is not defined
  * Notice:  Use of undefined constant ANIMALS - assumed ANIMALS...
  * Warning:  Illegal string offset 'dog'
  * if ANIMALS['dog'] is defined we do not get no warings notices
  * but we still receive The dog was not found */
print (defined(ANIMALS['dog'])) ? "2. Go for a walk with the dog\n" : "2. The dog was not found\n";
```

**3.** regardless of whether the `ANIMALS`, `ANIMALS['dog']` is defined or not, I get Warning:

```
/* Warning:  defined() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...*/  
print defined(array('ANIMALS' => 'dog')) ? "3. Go for a walk with the dog\n" : "3. The dog was not found\n";
```

**4.** I get Notice if `ANIMALS['dog']` is not defined

```
/* Notice: Use of undefined constant ANIMALS - assumed 'ANIMALS' */
print (isset(ANIMALS['dog'])) ? "4. Go for a walk with the dog\n" : "4. The dog was not found\n";
```

**5.** So am I correct that there is only one option left then?

```
print (defined('ANIMALS') && isset(ANIMALS['dog'])) ? "Go for a walk with the dog\n" : "The dog was not found\n";
```

Comment: Well `ANIMALS` is the constant; and the array key `dog` is simply part of the value that is defined for that constant; so it seems logical that `defined()` won't check for a value within the constant, only for the constant itself; so yes, logically this should be a two step check

Comment: @Mark Well for me that seems logical only in extent as PHP v < 7 define should only accept `string` ;)

Comment: PHP <7 would accept any scalar, not just string; but to check the type and whether it was defined was still a 2-step process.... `define('TESTMODE', true); if (defined('TESTMODE') && TESTMODE) {
    ...
}`

Comment: If in the future constants may evaluate to scalar values, arrays or objects then One could get similar question and want to easily check objects property. Don't they? instead of  `(defined('ANIMALS') && isset(ANIMALS->dog))`

Comment: The principle still holds it isn't `ANIMALS['dog']` that's defined as the constant, it's `ANIMALS`.... the fact that a constant is defined doesn't tell you anything about the value of that constant, simply the fact that it is defined..... you always have (and likely always will) need to make two separate tests, one for whether the constant (name) is defined, and another to identify facets of the value of the constant.... there isn't any shortcut to do both tests in a single call....

Comment: there isn't anything forgotten, `defined()` still does exactly what it's supposed to do, test for the existence of a Constant, nothing more and nothing less, and nothing to do with any value assigned to that constant.... `Checks whether a given named constant exists`

Comment: @Mark Well that's the thing I guess that I consider  ANIMALS['dog'] as constant in kind of constant namespace ANIMALS instead of taking it as just a array key.

Comment: I guess what you want is an equivalent of `isset` for constants which works like `isdefined(ANIMALS['dog'])`, and the answer is it doesn't exist at the moment. You can easily implement it as userspace function, and you can suggest it to the PHP dev team for implementation if you're convinced it's an oversight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP 7 allows you to `define` a constant array, but what is being defined as a constant in that case is *the array itself*, not its individual elements. In every other regard the constant functions as a typical array, so you'll need to use conventional methods to test for the existence of a specific key within it.

Try this:

```
define('ANIMALS', array(
    'dog'  => 'black',
    'cat'  => 'white',
    'bird' => 'brown'
));

print (defined('ANIMALS') && array_key_exists('dog', ANIMALS)) ?
    "Go for a walk with the dog\n" : "The dog was not found\n";
```

Comment: That would indeed right to use when you expect ANIMALS to be array as `key => val` pair, however if you have `define('ANIMALS', array('dog','cat','bird'));` you can't use array_key_exists and could only use option 5 `isset` or `in_array` instead.